# permission denied for composer in /usr/local/bin/

Tags: php, linux, permissions, composer-php

I followed the documentation on https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally to install composer globally on arch linux. When I do `composer self-update`, I get this message:

```
  [ErrorException]                                                                                    
  rename(/home/hannes/.composer/cache/composer-temp.phar,/usr/local/bin/composer): Permission denied
```

The permissions in `/usr/local/bin/` (I changed them to 777, but it did not help):

```
-rwxrwxrwx  1 hannes users 1104202 30. Mai 18:07 composer
```

In my home directory I did this:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 .composer/
```

In `/etc/php/php.ini`, the `open_basedir` looks so:

```
open_basedir = /srv/http/:/home/:/tmp/:/usr/share/pear/:/usr/share/webapps/:/usr/local/bin/
```

I also tried `sudo composer self-update` but it did not work as well and is possibly not the right way. (?). What else could I try to make this work?

Comment: You should check the permissions of the _directory_ `/usr/local/bin/`, not the file within. The process has to write into the directory which must be granted. And, apart from that, a hint: _do not always set everything to 777_. There is no reason for that and it makes your system vulnerable.

Comment: ok, should I `chown` the directory `/usr/local/bin` for my user (me) ?   It looks like this : `drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 30. Mai 18:08 bin` It looks as if it should be owned only by root, not a user.. (?)

Comment: Instead of starting a comment flow here I posted an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now, there is a package for composer in arch linux which works for me:

```
sudo pacman -S composer
```

Answer (score 48):

On Ubuntu server >= 16.04

FIRST

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/composer
```

AND

```
cd ~/.cache/composer
chmod 755 composer-temp.phar
sudo mv composer-temp.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Comment: `cd ~/.cache/composer` should be `cd ~/.composer/cache`

Comment: This worked for me in Amazon ec2 instance. Of course you have to do the change suggested by Oliver Tappin.

Comment: `~/.cache/composer` OR `~/.composer/cache` depend on which way composer was installed.

On my installations, locations are `~/.cache/composer`

I install composer like that :

`curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php`

Comment: This is my preferred answer. You do not have to change permissions or anything.

Comment: shouldn't it be `sudo cp ...` to always keep a temporary copy ?

Comment: worked for me, before you cd into /.cache/composer download dezired composer.phar and move it there, then use the correct file name for the composer-temp.phar, in my case it was composer.phar, then continue with the next commands. Thanks worked for me : )

Answer (score 36):

this might be the case if you have downloaded `composer.phar` directly ,

but not by running `php composer-setup.php`

make `composer.phar` executable with following command before moving it to `/usr/local/bin/composer` or after moving

`sudo chmod 755 composer.phar`

composer-setup.php will make this change for us by default

Comment: I did this and it worked for me. Not sure if it was doing the chmod before moving into /usr/local/bin or just reinstalling composer. Doesn't make sense since it had correct permissions already, but it works without error now.

Comment: May i know where is the path /usa/local/bin @Raaghu

Comment: @Gem This is a directory path in linux OS.

Comment: @Raaghu How can run in windows platform i am using composer.

Comment: @Gem Just do a right-click on the cmd-console and click "Run as admin". Then you can run the self-update command. It's kind of the same like running "sudo" in Linux.

Answer (score 16):

You should check the permissions of the directory /usr/local/bin/, not just the file within. The process has to write both, the file and into the directory which both must be granted.

Apart from that, a general hint: do not always set everything to 777. There is no reason for that and it makes your system vulnerable.

According to the line you posted in the last comment the directory is currently writeable *only* for the root user himself. That would explain the error you get. You should *not* make your own user account the owner, Linux systems are multi user environments. Instead think about one of these approaches:

- add the account that is meant to execute the `composer` to the group root (a user account can belong to several groups) and make the directory group writeable
- change the groups ownership of the directory to a group that account is a member of and make the directory group writeable
- use the `sudo` utility to install and update the `composer` utility

The last option is the typically chosen and preferred one. It leaves permissions as they are (conservative) and only uses raised privileges for system maintenance jobs like installation and upgrade.

Comment: How can I do the steps you describe in bullets? Linux commands are not my expertise

Comment: 1. find your user [whoami] 2.add user to root group [sudo adduser yourusername root] 3. restart terminal

Comment: Linux commands would have been better-

Answer (score 16):

Use sudo command for any command which writes to root files of folder. It worked for me.

use sudo "your command"

Comment: That might be the sledgehammer approach.

Comment: Avoid using sudo in composer. https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/how-to-install-untrusted-packages-safely.md

Comment: You should not run Composer as root/super user. See https://getcomposer.org/root for details.

Answer (score 4):

Even after moving the file via `sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer` I was getting a permission error when trying to run the `composer` command. `sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/composer` fixed things for me.

Answer (score 3):

You could temporarily add the rights to your working user, then update composer w/o errors and then get back the rights.

```
sudo chmod 777 /usr/bin/
composer self-update
sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/
```

Answer (score 2):

This did the job for me on Centos 7

```
chown -R apache:apache path/to/composer
chmod 755 path/to/composer
```

Comment: could you please explain what it does to clarify your answer? thanks in advance!

Comment: first command assigns apache as an owner of the folder. The Second command makes the folder "readable, writable, executable" for user and group, and "readable, executable" for other.

Answer (score 2):

make sure composer already at `/usr/local/bin` and then do following things

```
chmod 755 composer
```

if permission denied, add `sudo`

Answer (score 2):

For those who are using shared server here are the steps.

Let's first download composer file.

- `cd ~`
- `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php`

Now we can access composer by:

- `~/composer.phar`

Assuming you have `/public_html` in  root directory, here are the steps to use latest composer.

- `cd public_html`
- `~/composer.phar update`

In future, if you want to update composer:

- `~/composer.phar self-update`

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

My solution on macOs was the following:

First delete the directory yo created. Somehing like '/usr/local/bin/composer' using this command: rmdir /usr/local/bin/composer.

Now try to install composer again using Homebrew :

Step 1: brew install composer.
Step 2: brew link composer.

Now you can run composer in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

- For composer 2

  ```
  sudo composer self-update --2
  ```
- For composer 1

  ```
  sudo composer self-update --1
  ```

Comment: Can you give an explanation on how this solves the problem ?

Comment: I think this solves the problem because using `sudo` is a suggestion from the official composer documentation :
https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#self-update-selfupdate


If you have installed Composer for your entire system, you may have to run the command with root privileges

`sudo -H composer self-update`

Answer (score 0):

```
chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Answer (score -2):

if permission denied you should use the command with sudo like:

```
sudo composer self-update
```

Comment: Never ever use sudo in composer commands.