# Issue with "$ composer dumpautoload" on Cloud9, Cannot create cache directory

Tags: php, laravel-5, cloud9-ide, artisan-migrate, laravel-seeding

I'm having an issue with Artison migrate and seeding recongnizing classes. I've read that composer dumpautoload can fix the problem but I'm now having a problem running dump-autoload on Cloud9.

When I run: `$ composer dump-autoload`

I get the following error:

```
[ErrorException]
file_put_contents(/home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

When I run:

```
$ composer update
```

I get the following:

```
Cannot create cache directory /home/ubuntu/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
Cannot create cache directory /home/ubuntu/.composer/cache/files/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
You are running composer with xdebug enabled. This has a major impact on runtime performance. See https://getcomposer.org/xdebug
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Removing symfony/yaml (v3.1.5)
Update failed (Could not delete /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/symfony/yaml/Dumper.php: )
```

It looks like a problem with permissions. My question is: How do I fix these in the Cloud9 environment?

Comment: Looks like there could be some similar threads that would help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30956424/permission-denied-for-composer-in-usr-local-bin