# laravel add version to composer.json postAutoloadDump fails

Tags: laravel, composer-php

The composer.json of my laravel 5.6 project didn't have a "version" specifier.

So I added to my composer.json:

```
"version": "0.1.0"
```

After that, when I run `composer install`, `composer update foo/bar` or `composer dump-autoload` the following error occurs:

```
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\Process\ProcessUtils::escapeArgument() in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Util/ProcessExecutor.php:134
Stack trace:
#0 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(260): Composer\Util\ProcessExecutor::escape('1')
#1 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(232): Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->getPhpExecCommand()
#2 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(96): Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch(Object(Composer\Script\Event))
#3 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Autoload/AutoloadGenerator.php(312): Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatchScript('post-autoload-d...', true, Array, Array)
#4 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Installer.php(301): Composer\Autoload\AutoloadGenerator->dump(Object(Composer\Config), Object(Composer\Repository\InstalledFilesystemRepository), Object in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Util/ProcessExecutor.php on line 134

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\Process\ProcessUtils::escapeArgument() in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Util/ProcessExecutor.php:134
Stack trace:
#0 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(260): Composer\Util\ProcessExecutor::escape('1')
#1 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(232): Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->getPhpExecCommand()
#2 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(96): Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch(Object(Composer\Script\Event))
#3 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Autoload/AutoloadGenerator.php(312): Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatchScript('post-autoload-d...', true, Array, Array)
#4 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Installer.php(301): Composer\Autoload\AutoloadGenerator->dump(Object(Composer\Config), Object(Composer\Repository\InstalledFilesystemRepository), Object in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Util/ProcessExecutor.php on line 134
```

When I remove the `version` specifier, everything works as expected.

Here's my composer.json

```
{
    "name": "myvendor/myproject",
    "description": "",
    "keywords": [],
    "license": "MIT",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.6.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.4",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.6",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "^2.10",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

So it tells me that `Symfony\Component\Process\ProcessUtils::escapeArgument` is undefined. I also found https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/21281 and https://github.com/eyewitness/eye/issues/8 but I have problems putting it all to together to sort the problem out.

Again, when I remove `version` from composer.json, the problem is gone.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out that the error was caused by the composer version I was using.

I am using a laradock environment and `composer --verison` was `1.5.5`. After updating composer to `1.6.3`, the problem was gone.

However, if you experience the same problem, you will most likely have the same difficulties, updating composer in the workspace container of laradock. You cannot simply `composer selfupdate` there, because composer will have problems moving a temp file to `/usr/local/bin` due to permission settings.

I fixed it by adding the following section to my laradock/workspace/Dockerfile-72:

```
#####################################
# Composer:
#####################################

## FIX laradock/workspace permission problem

USER root

RUN rm /usr/local/bin/composer

USER laradock

RUN cd /home/laradock && php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');" && \
    php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === '544e09ee996cdf60ece3804abc52599c22b1f40f4323403c44d44fdfdd586475ca9813a858088ffbc1f233e9b180f061') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;" && \
    php composer-setup.php && \
    php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"

USER root 

RUN mv /home/laradock/composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

## ENDFIX
```

I guess, the problem is, that https://github.com/laradock/workspace/blob/master/Dockerfile-72 doesn't execute composer-setup.php (see answer of @Raaghu here: [permission denied for composer in /usr/local/bin/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30956424/permission-denied-for-composer-in-usr-local-bin#answer-44201828)).

Maybe the problem could have been fixed easier by simply adding this to the laradock/workspace Dockerfile:

```
USER root

RUN chown laradock:laradock /usr/local/bin/composer
```

But I didn't test this setup and I'm not sure.